# In appengine how would i move my db.Blob's into the Blobstore

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

I have a bunch of images which I have stored in db.Blob's and am serving.
I'd like to take advantage of the high availability BlobStore recently announced.
How would I go about moving my blob's to the Blobstore.

The docs seem to indicate the only way to add to the Blobstore is via a file upload form.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest idea is to create a migration task which sends images as multipart data to your request handler storing data into Blobstore.

For creating migration task see http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/

Since sockets are disabled, the only way to send multipart data is through the URLFetch api (http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/)

Sending multipart data can be done with the following snippet: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/146306-http-client-to-post-using-multipartform-data/

Answer (score 1):

I'd actually advise to wait a little while. Programmatic creation of blobs is on the [roadmap](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/roadmap.html), and should be coming up soon. If it's urgent though, then Piotr's solution sounds great.